# show an array with an indice in variable on php

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to have that code working but I still scratch my head...

```
$nomListe = array();
...
echo $nomListe[$cptList]
```

Thanks for helping me

**EDIT:**

```
print_r($nomListe);
echo $cptList;

echo $nomListe[$cptList];
```

gave me :

Array ( [0] => webdesign [1] => php [2] => asp [3] => ergonomie [4] => framework [5] => webdesign [6] => autre ) 
7

OK allright, I'm using the index 7 on an array that only have index until 6... Hum... i'm so ... tired?? sorry

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: Your array has 7 elements, with a 0 starting index.  I imagine your logic to come up with the number 7 has a starting index of 1 reserving 0 for an empty circumstance which is common, for instance `count()`.  You should simply need to subtract 1 from your identifier to apply it to the array index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print arrays use `print_r()`

```
 <?php
 $things = array ('f' => 'fork', 's' => 'spoon'); 
 print_r ($things);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

http://php.about.com/od/phpfunctions/g/print_r_php.htm

```
<?php
 $Names = array ('a' => 'Angela', 'b' => 'Bradley', 'c' => array ('Cade', 'Caleb')); 
 print_r ($Names);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To see the details you could always use `var_dump` of your array.

```
<?php
 $foo = array ('b' => 'bar', 'u' => 'uped', 'a' => 'around'); 
 var_dump($foo);
 ?>
```